# blank-space/border won't go away in table tr

Tags: html, css, html-table, newsletter

I have this newsletter markup:

```
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0"  style="font-family:verdana,'Myriad Pro', Arial; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;">
    <tr valign="bottom" height="127" style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;margin:0;margin-bottom:-2px;" >
        <td height="141" valign="bottom">
                            <img width="608" height="141" src="http://toniweb.us/m/demos/headPildoraLarge.png" />                                
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                      /*Rest of table ommited*/
    </tr>
```

The thing is that after the `<tr>` containing the headPildoraLarge.png img there is a ~2px gap on the bottom wich I can't delete...

This is visible in outlook IE 5,6,7    (not in FF, IE8 or others) but are the tarjet ones in this case....

How can I remove the gap?

Full HTML in action: http://toniweb.us/m/demos/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write this in your css :

```
img{
 border:0;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Dude; i don't fuc*** get it; vertical-align:top? isn't it supoused to be bottom? but it works :D

Answer (score 2):

just add `vertical-align: bottom` for that image to your stylesheet - somehow like:

```
td img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

for more information, read [this great article](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/vertical-align/). the gap you're seeing is the difference between the baseline-and bottomline of you font, because inline-images are aligned to the baseline by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the below style on image

```
<img width="608" height="141" src="http://toniweb.us/m/demos/headPildoraLarge.png" style="vertical-align:bottom;" />
```